# British TV series about shooting at school

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I remember watching a series several years ago (maybe 4 - 5 years) on British television, but I missed one episode so I never really got the gist of the ending, and this has led to it being an itch-to-scratch.

Trouble, is I can't remember the name. But I do recall a few scenes - so, spoilers ahead!

Several kids go into the school. The revelation/the beginning of the shooting is initiated when one of the boys makes a remark to a girl about seeing his 'big gun'. She gives him a disgusted retort, before the boy pulls out the real gun.

There are a few scenes in a bathroom where a child is shot dead. It's later revealed there's also a bomb in the ventilation system.

A black boy who was involved in the plan committed suicide by cutting his elbow veins. It's later revealed that he didn't want to participate.

The boys in the shooting meet up and have a discussion during which one is reluctant. One of the boys makes a remark about not pussying out now, and how this is their chance. There's writing on a chalkboard behind him.

The ending involves a tactical team going to breach a laboratory-style room and shooting an armed child as the detective finds out that the boy shot in that room is innocent.

The story is sometimes narrated through tapes left by one of the main shooters.

Comment: When did you watched it (several is bit vague), is it British show or non British? Anyways nice detailed question.

Comment: British, and I'm not too sure about how long ago it was. I'd say you're looking at the 4/5 year mark.

Comment: Was the school shooting a major part of the show (e.g. it was all about that, set over multiple episodes) or was the school shooting only in a single episode?

Comment: It spanned across multiple episodes, and everything before the shooting was leading up to it.

Comment: This sounds like an episode of the BBC serial Waterloo Road.  That had a story about 3 years ago along these lines.

Answer (score 4):

This was a two part episode of *Silent Witness* from the BBC. It was Nikki and Harry that were caught up in it.

It was a great episode. [The episode was called Shadows](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1568005/?ref_=ttep_ep7). Series 13 in 2010.

> The team attend at the apparent suicide of student Jason Renfrew at the local university. The Dean tells Leo Jason complained to her about racist bullying and he is found to have swallowed a chip containing photos of the alleged bullies, as well as having a handgun in his locker. Soon afterwards a gunman goes on the rampage, killing several people including the policeman investigating Jason's death. Nikki and Harry are trapped in a classroom with some students, one of whom, the mortally wounded Matt Frisk, was one of Jason's tormentors. Commander Somerville leads the police team who release them though it is Harry who finds the severely injured gunman. However, he fails to spot the bomb planted on campus.

Comment: the episode  was called Shadows. Series 13 in 2010

Comment: Can you describe the synopsis of that episode?